# Poor performance with LXD/LXC. Extremely high CPU steal in the containers

Tags: pi-3b+, virtualization

I've got a pi 3 B+ running Raspbian 10. I installed LXD using a snap package.

There's two LXC containers running on my machine. One is an nginx reverse proxy and the other is running pihole.

Both containers are very slow to do basically anything even though they're not under any appreciable load. If I check `top` inside each container, I see that the CPU steal time is 99%.

I've also noticed the command `lxc list` sometimes takes a very long time to complete.

The host is doing basically nothing besides running those two containers.

output of `top` on host:

```
top - 15:46:10 up 20 days, 17:11,  2 users,  load average: 0.38, 1.96, 3.19
Tasks: 169 total,   1 running, 168 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.2 us,  0.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.4 id,  1.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :    926.8 total,     46.9 free,    222.0 used,    657.8 buff/cache
MiB Swap:    100.0 total,     81.5 free,     18.5 used.    637.2 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                    
  697 pi        20   0   10220   3052   2544 R   1.0   0.3   0:00.73 top                                        
  416 root      20   0   28596   1316   1212 S   0.3   0.1   4:17.39 rngd                                       
32458 1000033   20   0  188540   9316   5980 S   0.3   1.0   0:00.71 php-cgi                                    
    1 root      20   0   34744   6456   5104 S   0.0   0.7   0:47.88 systemd                                    
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:03.58 kthreadd                                   
    3 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_gp                                     
    4 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 rcu_par_gp                                 
    8 root       0 -20       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 mm_percpu_wq                               
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   3:03.04 ksoftirqd/0                                
   10 root      20   0       0      0      0 I   0.0   0.0   4:22.71 rcu_sched                                  
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.28 migration/0                                
   12 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0                                    
   13 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/1                                    
   14 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.49 migration/1                                
   15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   1:44.52 ksoftirqd/1                                
   18 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/2                                    
   19 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.45 migration/2
```

output of `top` in a container:

```
top - 14:47:09 up 20 days, 17:12,  0 users,  load average: 0.38, 1.67, 3.01
Tasks:  23 total,   1 running,  22 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.3 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si, 99.7 st
MiB Mem :    926.8 total,     46.9 free,    222.0 used,    657.9 buff/cache
MiB Swap:    100.0 total,     81.5 free,     18.5 used.    637.2 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                    
22744 www-data  20   0  188540   9384   5980 S   0.3   1.0   0:00.82 php-cgi                                    
22745 www-data  20   0  188540   9316   5980 S   0.3   1.0   0:00.82 php-cgi                                    
22748 www-data  20   0  188540   9316   5980 S   0.3   1.0   0:00.83 php-cgi                                    
22853 pihole    20   0   53360   6072   2820 S   0.3   0.6   0:01.41 pihole-FTL                                 
23453 root      20   0    8388   2480   2112 R   0.3   0.3   0:00.03 top                                        
    1 root      20   0   33656   7180   5380 S   0.0   0.8   1:15.39 systemd                                    
   43 root      20   0   36892  10596   9856 S   0.0   1.1   0:45.65 systemd-journal                            
   77 root      20   0   15100   2412   1952 S   0.0   0.3   0:05.53 systemd-udevd                              
   83 systemd+  20   0   21768   4288   3608 S   0.0   0.5   3:06.23 systemd-network                            
   85 root      20   0    7432   2020   1812 S   0.0   0.2   0:10.51 cron                                       
   86 message+  20   0    6296   2644   2140 S   0.0   0.3   0:09.47 dbus-daemon                                
   90 root      20   0   23312   7412   2592 S   0.0   0.8   0:00.45 networkd-dispat                            
   91 syslog    20   0   20092   2528   1960 S   0.0   0.3   0:05.68 rsyslogd                                   
  106 systemd+  20   0   18084   7448   4320 S   0.0   0.8   0:36.92 systemd-resolve                            
  129 root      20   0    1764   1104    892 S   0.0   0.1   0:42.88 dhcpcd                                     
  143 root      20   0    6168   1432   1352 S   0.0   0.2   0:00.00 agetty                                     
  165 pihole    20   0   13360   6048   5192 S   0.0   0.6   0:01.38 systemd                                    
  170 pihole    20   0   33164   2488    868 S   0.0   0.3   0:00.00 (sd-pam)                                   
21141 root      20   0    6516   2608   2280 S   0.0   0.3   0:00.04 bash                                       
22568 root      20   0   12360   5076   4440 S   0.0   0.5   0:02.96 systemd-logind                             
22712 www-data  20   0    6800   3044   2392 S   0.0   0.3   0:00.43 lighttpd                                   
22739 www-data  20   0  188260  15520  12604 S   0.0   1.6   0:00.07 php-cgi                                    
22743 www-data  20   0  188540  10436   6800 S   0.0   1.1   0:00.87 php-cgi
```

The only bit of configuration I've done is set my default profile to use a macvlan.

Is there possibly something I need to correctly configure for my containers to run correctly?

Let me know if there's any more info I can provide.